# Saving a string hierarchy for code generation

Tags: java, code-generation

I have a question about String storage.

I use a code generation framework (In java, generates java) which uses a lot of strings that I want to organize in some way.

I was thinking of having the strings in functions, which will allow me to add javadocs and such to the strings. There will be a lot of functions, I planned to split them in different classes depending of the type (like methods or classes for example). I do not have any database so it must be in the project.

How do I best do this? **With static final on everything it would be easy to access, but is there any downside to this?** (I don't use multithreading btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I they are constant Strings, then definitely make them constant by declaring them static and final. And declare these constants where they logically belong, i.e. in the class that depends on this constant for its logic.

I don't see any downside, on the contrary.